# Necessity of denseness and completeness for a surjective monotone being continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity, order-theory

It turns out that the familiar result that surjective monotones $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are continuous extends to general LOTS (linearly ordered topological spaces):

> **Theorem**. If $X$, $Y$ are LOTS with $Y$ being dense and complete, then any surjective monotone $X\to Y$ is continuous.

(The same proof from $\mathbb{R\to R}$ case sails through.)

The necessity of surjectivity is clear by considering the function $f\colon \mathbb {R\to R}$ given by $f(x) := x$ for $x < 0$ and $f(x) := x +1$ for $x\ge 1$.

However, I am having trouble finding two examples that show the necessity of denseness and, respectively completeness of the codomain space. Any leads?

Comment: @Ulli Corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*dense-in-itself suffices:*

Let $(X, \le), (Y, \le)$ be linearly ordered sets equipped with the order topology,
$Y$ dense-in-itself (i.e. for each $y, z \in Y, y < z$, it is $(y, z) \neq \emptyset$.

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y $ be a monotone increasing, surjective map.
Then f is continuous.

PROOF. Let $x \in X$, $f(x) \in V$ open in $Y$.
Case 1: $f(x)$ is neither minimum nor maximum of $Y$.
Then there exist $u, v \in Y$ such that $u < f(x) < v$ and $(u, v) \subset V$.
Since $Y$ is dense-in-itself, we may assume that $[u, v] \subset V$.
Since $f$ is surjective, pick $a, b \in X$ such that
$f(a) = u, f(b) = v$.
Hence $a < x < b$ and $f( (a,b) ) \subset [u. v] \subset V$.

Other cases: similar.

It doesn't hold in general, if $Y$ is not dense-in-itself:

$f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \{0, 1\}, \space
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if } x < 0 \\
1, & \text{if } 0 \le x
\end{cases}   $